# Split string and take last element

Tags: sql, sql-server, url, split

I have a table with this values:

```
Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681/ArticleID/2218/Diet.aspx
OurStory/MeettheFoodieandtheMD.aspx
TheFood/OurMenu.aspx
```

I want to get this

```
Diet.aspx
MeettheFoodieandtheMD.aspx
OurMenu.aspx
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Can't you do this in DAL or presentation layer? i.e. not in database but say .NET client?

Comment: you mean by creating a program to do it?Yes i can do it but is any way to do it in sql server?

Comment: It's much easier to implement say in C#, that's what I mean. But still possible in T-SQL.

Comment: i know i think i might do it in c# no one is answering :P

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The way to do it in SQL :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( string , LEN(string) -  CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(string)) + 2  , LEN(string)  ) FROM SAMPLE;
```

JSFiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41ead/11

Comment: thank you this is the correct answer because some fields don't have a '/' :)

Comment: Perhaps not applicable to the question in context, but generally speaking, this solution does't work for entries with: 1) A single token (no separators). In this case, we expect the single value. 2) A single-character token.

Comment: I know this is an ancient post, but it helped me today. I was looking to drop the last element of a string, which I tweaked your SQL to do: `substring(Name, 1, len(string)-CHARINDEX(' ', reverse(string)))`

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(columnName), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(columnName)) - 1))
FROM   tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31f94/9)

ORHER SOURCE(s)

- [REVERSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx)
- [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)
- [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Comment: it gives me this error:Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: +1 Cool solution. Just before this appeared I was typing a comment that you'd probably need to use CHARINDEX in a stored proc / function loop.

Comment: @AntonioPapa check the syntax on your code, probably you left something. see the sql fiddle link.

Answer (score 10):

Try this. It's easier.

```
SELECT RIGHT(string, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(string)) -1) FROM TableName
```

Comment: this won't work if the separator character doesn't occur in the string

Answer (score 8):

Please try:

```
select url,(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', url, 1)=0 THEN url ELSE RIGHT(url, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(url)) - 1) END)
from(
    select 'Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681/ArticleID/2218/Diet.aspx' as url union
    select 'OurStory/MeettheFoodieandtheMD.aspx' as url union
    select 'MeettheFoodieandtheMD.aspx' as url
)xx
```

Comment: it works your way but it gives me this error:
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: I guess adding a case condition will remove the error. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: was what I wanted. works with elements that have not the char separator

Comment: This works really well. Handles NULLs, single-tokens (no separators) even with lengths of 1 or 0 characters.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly more compact way of doing this (similar to ktaria's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59880884/470014) but in SQL Server) would be

```
SELECT TOP 1 REVERSE(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(REVERSE(fullPath), '/') AS fileName
```

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT REVERSE ((
    SELECT TOP 1 value FROM STRING_SPLIT(REVERSE('Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681/ArticleID/2218/Diet.aspx'), '/')
)) AS fName
Result: Diet.aspx
```

Standard `STRING_SPLIT` does not allow to take last value.

The trick is to reverse the string (`REVERSE`) before splitting with `STRING_SPLIT`, get the first value from the end (`TOP 1 value`) and then the result needs to be reversed again (`REVERSE`) to restore the original chars sequence.

Here is the common approach, when working with SQL table:

```sql
SELECT REVERSE ((
    SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(REVERSE(mySearchString), '/')
)) AS myLastValue
FROM myTable
```

Comment: string_split without the ordinal parameter does NOT guarantee order. TOP 1 without an ORDER BY clause is logical nonsense. This "works" based on luck.

Comment: Note that there is now string_split with ordinal in some flavors of SQL  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent for PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT reverse(split_part(reverse(column_name), '/', 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

more simple and elegant :

```
select reverse(SPLIT_PART(reverse('Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681/ArticleID/2218/Diet.aspx'), '/',1))
```

Comment: Nice, but your solution is *not* SQL Server :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( attachment, LEN(attachment) 
     - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(attachment)) + 2, LEN(attachment)  ) AS filename 
FROM filestable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too

```
( SELECT TOP(1) value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(#string, '/') 
ORDER BY CHARINDEX('/' + value + '/', '/' + #string+ '-') DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected jazzytomato's solution for single character tokens (`D`) and for single tokens (`Diet.aspx`)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( string , LEN(string) -  CHARINDEX('/','/'+REVERSE(string)) + 2  , LEN(string)  ) FROM SAMPLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have more simple solve

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, '/', -1)', 1) FROM SAMPLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to do this, though does not work in all versions

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', -1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your contribution. However SUBSTRING_INDEX is not supported on MS SQL server as tagged on this question.

Answer (score -1):

```
reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(yourString),0,CHARINDEX('/',reverse(yourString)))) as stringLastPart
```

Comment: Add some explanation to avoid this post to consider as low quality post by `stackoverflow`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create Table #temp
(
ID int identity(1,1) not null,
value varchar(100) not null
)

DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(100);

INSERT INTO #temp(value) SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT('C:\Users\Documents\Datavalidation\Input.csv','\')
SET @fileName=(SELECT TOP 1 value from #temp ORDER BY ID DESC);
SELECT @fileName AS File_Name;

DROP TABLE #temp
```