# Separate string by just comma

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I created a column that concatenate all the strings like this

```
|              col1                 |
|-----------------------------------|
|   key,board, warrior,123,ADD      |
|-----------------------------------|
| First,First, Last, Name,112,Delete|
```

and I'm trying to figure out to a way to split them with just comma, not space and comma.

```
SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',' 1) AS COL1,
    SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',' 2) AS COL2,
    SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',' 3) AS COL3,
    SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',' 4) AS COL4
FROM TABLE1
```

This separates everything with comma like this

```
| col1 | col2  | col3  | col4 |
|-----------------------------|
| key  | board |warrior| 123  |
| First| First |  Last | Name |
```

And I want to split them like this below.

```
| col1 | col2              | col3| col4  |
|----------------------------------------|
| key  | board, warrior    | 123 | ADD   |
| First| First, Last, Name | 112 | Delete|
```

I couldn't find a good reference for this. Please help!

Comment: Sounds like you want to only split your strings at the first two and the last comma. Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412898/split-string-and-take-last-element

Comment: Csv in columns is one of those things that seems like a good idea when you do it, and then reveals itself as not such a good idea shortly after it becomes difficult to change

Comment: Perhaps you should use a delimiter that doesn't appear in your data, like a new line. Or use json, xml, arrays or similar (whatever your db has support for parsing and querying)

Comment: Or even just do it how we would classically do it in a database - with a one:many related table

Answer (score 2):

One way is to [REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html) the troublesome input, with some safe tokens, and then change it back:

```
SELECT  
    replace(column1, ', ', '$$') as col1
    ,replace(SPLIT_PART(col1, ',', 1),'$$',', ') AS out1
    ,replace(SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',', 2),'$$',', ') AS out2
    ,replace(SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',', 3),'$$',', ') AS out3
    ,replace(SPLIT_PART(COL1, ',', 4),'$$',', ') AS out4
FROM VALUES
('key,board, warrior,123,ADD'),
('First,First, Last, Name,112,Delete');
```

gives:

| COL1 | OUT1 | OUT2 | OUT3 | OUT4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key,board$$warrior,123,ADD | key | board, warrior | 123 | ADD |
| First,First$$Last$$Name,112,Delete | First | First, Last, Name | 112 | Delete |

So putting that in a sub-select, to get cleaner output like you asked for:

```
create table concat_cols(col1 text);

insert into concat_cols values 
    ('key,board, warrior,123,ADD'),
    ('First,First, Last, Name,112,Delete');
```

```
SELECT  
    replace(split_col1[0],'$$',', ') AS out1
    ,replace(split_col1[2],'$$',', ') AS out2
    ,replace(split_col1[2],'$$',', ') AS out3
    ,replace(split_col1[3],'$$',', ') AS out4
FROM (
    SELECT split(replace(col1, ', ', '$$'), ',') as split_col1
    FROM concat_cols
);
```

| OUT1 | OUT2 | OUT3 | OUT4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key | board, warrior | 123 | ADD |
| First | First, Last, Name | 112 | Delete |

Next, maybe you have dynamic string concatenations, want to pull those apart. Using [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) to can have that

```
SELECT 
    f.seq as line,
    f.index as part,
    replace(f.value,'$$',', ') AS output
FROM concat_cols
    ,table(split_to_table(replace(col1, ', ', '$$'), ',')) f;
```

| LINE | PART | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | key |
| 1 | 2 | board, warrior |
| 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 1 | 4 | ADD |
| 2 | 1 | First |
| 2 | 2 | First, Last, Name |
| 2 | 3 | 112 |
| 2 | 4 | Delete |