# How to combine multiple rows with similar (not same) id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried searching and found a lot of solutions for problems with "identical" id, but my problem is dealing with "similar" ids.

I have a table with a bunch of tasks, task description, and procedure notes. Each task may have multiple sub-tasks. **I need to combine all subtask information into one cell**. The table looks like below:

| TaskID | Description | Procedure Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task-1 | General Description | null |
| Task-1-1 | Step 1 Task | Step 1 Notes |
| Task-1-2 | Step 2 Task | Step 2 Notes |
| Task-1-3 | Step 3 Task | Step 3 Notes |
| C-Task-2 | General Description | null |
| C-Task-2-01 | Step 1 Task | Step 1 Notes |
| C-Task-2-02 | Step 2 Task | Step 2 Notes |

Desired Result (formatting keeps breaking sorry):

| TaskID | Description |

| Task-1 | Step 1 + Step 1 Notes, Step 2 + Step 2 Notes, Step 3 + Step 3 Notes |

Since the naming of TaskID is not consistent I can't just trim and compare. I have tried using XML PATH / STUFF, but that only lets me do one task at a time and I have hundreds. I also don't have access to STRING_AGG.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think, quite honestly the answers you're going to get will not solve your immediate issue because this is a data normalization and design problem that should be fixed. Because of, what I'm going to assume to be the unique key `TaskID` is inconsistent, and if it's varied to the point where you can't use any sort of business logic to extract meaningful identifiers from your column, I would say it's nearly impossible with any level of accuracy/certainty.

Comment: @EdwardRadcliffe Yeah I understand on the user end why this is inconsistent, but it is making this harder for me

Comment: 1. The TaskId structure is not clear. In your example, it seems that the left part of the children's TaskIDs is the same as that of the parent. Is that so? 2. Saying "XML PATH only lets me do one task" sounds plain incorrect to me. Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Will the procedure notes always null for the parent task row and not null for sub-task rows? If so, you can query the parent task separately. Then for the 'child' rows where 'Procedure notes' is not null, use the below advise to remove the last part of the value from task ID. you should be able to link your child row to the parent row.

[Split string and take last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412898/split-string-and-take-last-element)

Comment: This did let me separate the trailing "-1" or "-01" etc! I tried using TRIM to remove that part from the TaskID but it didn't work. I must not be on SQL Server 17 or later

Answer (score 1):

So I a assumed three things:

- there are two levels; top level tasks and sub tasks
- each task has null as procedure notes
- task name are included in sub-task name and it is not possible that task name can be part of another task name

based on these assumptions below is my attempt and a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e39d3e97782c58e66eb67e4e6d5ceca4)-

```
; with findtaskid as 
(
select taskid,cast('' as nvarchar(max)) as notes ,
row_number() over (order by t.taskid) as id,
cast(0 as int) as r2
from t 
where ProcedureNotes is NULL

union all 

select 
t.taskid, 
ISNULL(t.description,'') +' '+ ISNULL(t.procedurenotes,'') Notes,
id,
cast(row_number() over (order by t.taskid) as int) as r2
from 
findtaskid c join t 
on c.taskid<>t.taskid
and t.taskid like c.taskid +'%'
),
collates as
(
select taskid, notes, r2,id 
from findtaskid 
where r2=1

union all

select c.taskid, c.notes +'  '+ f.notes, f.r2, f.id
from findtaskid f join collates c
on c.id=f.id and f.r2=c.r2+1 

), lastrowoutput as
(
select taskid,notes, row_number() over (partition by id order by r2 desc) as r3
from collates

)
select taskid,notes from lastrowoutput where r3=1
```