# Found substring separated by pipe (|) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I want is to obtain a part of a text string that is between some pipes (`|`) this expression contains numbers and commas, does anyone have any suggestions on how to do it in MSSQL?

I have these examples:

`|5|61|363|SP-105|1000|KM|49|TNS|2.23|REN|449.089|LTR|1|FP|1348,1360|`
I want to get **1348,1360**.

`|18|66|410|SP-105|1804|KM|50|TNS|2.65|REN|681.8512|LTR|1.65|FP|1504,1526|`
I want to get **1504,1526**.

`|12-22|5-Aug-2021|SP-106 |857,868,869,870|5|tlaj-vcrz-xala-mx-gdl |2139KM |79990KG`
I want to get **857,868,869,870**.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Split string and take last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412898/split-string-and-take-last-element)

Comment: How do you know that out of the 8 chunks in your last example you want the 4th one?