# Split string and not take right of last element Presto

Tags: sql, split, presto

If I have a table with a value of:

```
Hello/Hi/Howdy/Bye
```

How can I extract the field by just capturing

```
Hello/Hi/Howdy
```

Using SQL, specifically Presto. I don't fully understand how to implement the reverse of answers to the question here: [Split string and take last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412898/split-string-and-take-last-element)

```
SELECT reverse(split_part(reverse(column_name), '/', 1))
```

For instance, the above would take the string, reverse it, split the first part, then reverses it to get the last part. Is there a way to capture the index of the last instance of '/' to implement into split_part() to do something like this:

```
split_part(rcolumn_name, '/', < index of last instance of '/' >)
```

Comment: Is it ok to solve it using `SQL Server`? based on the mentioned question `Split string and take last element`  I don't know if the `charindex and len` functions are supported by `Presto`

Comment: @Ahmed Unfortunately it is not supported in Presto.

Comment: The provided solution by Guru is more efficient and works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to remove the last `/` and everything after that - you can try using `regexp_replace`:

```sql
 select regexp_replace('Hello/Hi/Howdy/Bye', '(\/[^\/]*$)', '')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| Hello/Hi/Howdy |

Comment: Didn't think of using regex. Thanks @Guru Stron